# How to validate Google App ID and App Secret?

Tags: php, google-api, google-php-sdk

I'm using Google SDK to make some flows automatic. The user provides his own application ID and secret, then logs in.

How can I check whether Google Application ID and Application Secret are valid?

Comment: if its not valid authentication should return with an error. probably invalid client id.  I think the only way to test it will be to run a request.