# How to get Google application name from Google API / PHP SDK?

Tags: php, google-api, google-php-sdk

I'm using Google SDK, where user provides his own application ID and secret. After saving the credentials, I would like to display application's name.

Is there any way to get application's name from PHP SDK and/or API? I looked for it in the SDK core, but haven't found anything.

By application name I mean the one chosen as Project Name in the consent screen or at least the general Project Name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to get any information about the projects on Google Developer console.

There simply isn't an API for it.   nothing that lets you look at a user to see what apps they have and nothing to check on it based upon the client lid and secret associated with a project.

Comment: If that's true, I guess the best I can do is to call it just "Google Application", or for example "Google Application #123456...", where 123456 is the beginning of my Client ID.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you take a look at my another question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31241864/how-to-validate-google-app-id-and-app-secret ?